# problems with anchor ajax submit

Tags: jquery, anchor, form-submit

I had an anchor that submited a form with an ajax response. It used to work, but now, for some reason, the form is being submited and bypassing the ajax call

code:

```
    <script>                           
//makes anchor as submit
//searchmore is the id of the form
$('#searchmore a').click(function() {
$(this).parents('form').submit();
return false

});

//submit handling

$("#searchmore").submit(function() {

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
beforeSend: function(objeto){ /*before send function*/      },
url: $(this).attr('action'),
data: $(this).serialize(),
dataType: "text",
success: function(data){

$("#display_results").append(data);

}

});
return false;

});
</script>
```

if i submit the form with a submit button, the ajax response works great, therefore the anchor must be the problem

and it seems there are no errors in syntax, any suggestions?

edit: you can check the page [here](http://www.foodbook.cl/blog.php) the form is at the end. you can find the anchor (the small light-blue box that says "más resultados") and the submit button under it

Comment: I'm assuming `#searchmore` is the id of your form?

Comment: yes, ill update the post to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form[id=searchmore] a').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Ahhh, and try to debug if $('form[id=searchmore] a').click is triggered. Simply put alert in there to be sure.

Comment: Try add to <a href="#" onclick="return false;"> to check hot it respond.

Comment: Try this example, I've used your code: http://jsfiddle.net/5zdTZ/10/ There is probably some collision between plugins / js scripts? Did you included jquery library in your project? Unfortunatelly it's quite late now and I'm heading to bed. If it won't work I will check tomorrow morning. If you will still need help I will try my best. Cheers ;)

Comment: thx, but it seems the problem is still there... no idea why. I used the same method on other form and worked, this is drriving me crazy... you can check the web page: http://foodbook.cl/blog.php

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. the script was fine... there was another script messing up with jquery. I changed it and now it works

thx